# Does the sequence $A_n = \frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Does the sequence $A_n = \frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge to $0$?

If I take the limit of the equation, it seems that the top part goes to 1 and the bottom will go to infinity. So, I just wanted to check and be sure that it converges to 0 rather than think it does and find out that I'm wrong.

Comment: The top part does **not** go to 1!

Comment: Ah it is between -1 and 1! So I'll need to use L'Hospitals correct? Err looks like I need to use the squeeze theorem as per Luis' suggestion

Comment: L'Hospital can be used if there is an indeterminate expression of the $0/0$ of $\infty/\infty$ kind; in this case, you've got something bounded divided by something that grows to infinity -- so there is no need for the heavy caliber :-)

Comment: No l'Hospital, just $|A_n|\le \frac 1{\sqrt n}$ should be enough

Comment: Are the conditions satisfied for L'Hopital? If not, then you should not use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using squeeze theorem. The top does not go to 1.

Comment: Or the sandwich theorem, or whatever other ridiculously awesome names it has.

Comment: So, I would then find the limit of $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ which both go to 0. Essentially the limit is 0, but I did it incorrectly above?

Comment: Why did you drop the square roots from the bottom?

Comment: Twas a typo ;) was adding them in on the edit prior to your reply! (will accept your answer when it allows me)

Comment: Well if by above you mean your original statement, then yes. $\sin (n)$ does not tend to 1. It is the right idea.

Comment: One last thing before I accept, this means that anything involving sin(n) or cos(n) (regardless of coefficients) I'll have to apply the squeeze theorem?

Comment: No. In this particular case you can because you can squeeze it easily between two functions that you know tend to the same limit. In general you cannot do so. I would never say the same method works when limits are involved =]

Comment: Thank you very much Luis. I will be posting quite a few more questions shortly, hope you are around!

Answer (score 1):

notice since $x \to \sin x $ is bounded by $1$ for all $x$, then

$$ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

now apply the squeeze rule and the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to0$

Comment: Thank you Don! I appreciate it :)